# How to Get the F# Name of a Module, Function, etc. From Quoted Expression Match

Tags: f#, quotations

I continue to work on a printer for F# quoted expressions, it doesn't have to be perfect, but I'd like to see what is possible. The active patterns in `Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns` and `Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.DerivedPatterns` used for decomposing quoted expressions will typically provide `MemberInfo` instances when appropriate, these can be used to obtain the name of a property, function, etc. and their "declaring" type, such as a module or static class. The problem is, I only know how to obtain the `CompiledName` from these instances but I'd like the F# name. For example,

```
> <@ List.mapi (fun i j -> i+j) [1;2;3] @> |> (function Call(_,mi,_) -> mi.DeclaringType.Name, mi.Name);;
val it : string * string = ("ListModule", "MapIndexed")
```

How can this match be rewritten to return `("List", "mapi")`? Is it possible?

**FYI, here is my final polished solution from Stringer Bell and pblasucci's help:**

```
let moduleSourceName (declaringType:Type) =
    FSharpEntity.FromType(declaringType).DisplayName

let methodSourceName (mi:MemberInfo) =
    mi.GetCustomAttributes(true)
    |> Array.tryPick 
            (function
                | :? CompilationSourceNameAttribute as csna -> Some(csna)
                | _ -> None)
    |> (function | Some(csna) -> csna.SourceName | None -> mi.Name)

//usage:
let sourceNames =
    <@ List.mapi (fun i j -> i+j) [1;2;3] @> 
    |> (function Call(_,mi,_) -> mi.DeclaringType |> moduleSourceName, mi |> methodSourceName);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can check a method's custom attributes for `CompilationSourceNameAttribute`; its `SourceName` property should be what you want. I'd post an answer with a proper sample, but I'm not near a development computer at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! You could also post it on Tomas's http://fssnip.net :D

Comment: @Stringer Bell - thought you might be interested, I've started an open source project Unquote (http://code.google.com/p/unquote/) which incorporates a quotation printer, which I talk about more specifically here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448961/is-there-any-built-in-function-for-human-readable-f-quotations/4948660#4948660

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use F# powerpack for that purpose:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata
...
| Call(_, mi, _) ->
    let ty = Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata.FSharpEntity.FromType(mi.DeclaringType)
    let name = ty.DisplayName // name is List
```

However, I don't think if it's possible to retrieve function name with powerpack.

**Edit:**

As hinted by pblasucci, you can use `CompilationSourceName` attribute for retrieving source name:

```
let infos = mi.DeclaringType.GetMember(mi.Name)
let att = infos.[0].GetCustomAttributes(true)
let fName =
    (att.[1] :?> CompilationSourceNameAttribute).SourceName // fName is mapi
```